# can 'who liked you' data be achieved in Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I see a path to get what appears to be like counts ->  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes but this is no good.
I would like to know 'who liked me' or even better yet who 'liked' my POSTing (the ideal solution), and possibly a link to their profile.
FB has a public feed api which possibly will do this in the future, but it is closed as of now.

Is there any workaround for finding 'who liked my post' data in the Facebook api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the likes on a particular facebook post by issuing a request to the given end point when using graph api.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post_id.'/likes?limit=0 // for likes
```

or fQL

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id={object id} LIMIT 1000
```

you will receive the ids of users by which you can generate links to their profile.

getting the likes might depend on the user **privacy settings**.